# How do I install or get the dependency libexiv2-12

Tags: 12.04, installation, dependencies, 32-bit, gimp

I am trying to install UFraw as a Gimp plug-in and can't because I need the Libexiv2-12 dependency. How do I install this file so I can install UFraw.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 (i386)

Comment: Why don't you install ufraw from the official repository? That depends on libexiv2-11 which is in the repository, too.

Answer (score 1):

As Florian said above, you only need to install UFRaw from repository.

If you absolutely need to build and install UFRaw from source code, run:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep ufraw
```

This will get you all dependencies for building UFRaw.